# Tracking out of date tutorials on Ubuntu developer portal

Tags: discussion

I really think there needs to be a way to track the out of date tutorials on quickly/python/ubuntu developer portal.

I don't think anyone argues with that. Would you be for or against a question here that developed into:

1. a list of out of dates *or*
2. the answer is a link to some free blogging site where you could track it?

Comment: it could also be an ubuntu wiki page that is editable by anyone with a lanuchpad account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be a wiki page

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a list on meta with "up to date" or "out of date" because it's not actually a question

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be a list on the main site with "up to date" or "out of date" so we could dupe tutorial questions to it